# AWS ELB Load Sharing Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

We have 3 EC2 Instances(Apache Web Server) running under AWS ELB, it sharing load correctly but whenever any of Web Server down i.e. Web1 having some issue i.e. Disk Full or Apache Crash then still ELB trying to send request to that server which is already not responding or don't have capacity to respond, hence user who is connected to that server are getting error.

Question : Is there way to identify Fail server and force ELB to stop passing request to failed server?

FYI: Auto Scaling is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure [health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html) for your ELB. When the checks are failing, the elb will stop forwarding traffic to the unhealthy instance.